# AngularJS - Move Object from Controller 1 to Controller 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently learning AngularJS but I wasn't able to find a solution for this problem even though it seems trivial.

I have two lists / controllers that are getting created by factory service.

I want to remove an object from list 1 and add to list 2. When I display the object in the console after passing it, I can see it but it doesn't appear in my second list.

I have the code on GitHub - As you can see this is an assignment from coursera. 
https://github.com/alaimoclaudia/assignment2_solution

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: unfortunately, links to code on outside sites are not a replacement for code *in the question body*.  links can change, leaving the question completely unusable by others in the future.  You should [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I am answering your question, but I have created a plunker based on your github code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/oNvezy5IQ9EBKMpwWq7j?p=preview

I see only one list of items in the code:

```
[{
  name: "Milk",
  quantity: "10"
}, {
  name: "Donuts",
  quantity: "10"
}, {
  name: "Cookies",
  quantity: "10"
}, {
  name: "Chocolate",
  quantity: "10"
}, {
  name: "Apples",
  quantity: "10"
}];
```

And it seems like the ui behaves as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code - that helped! I figured out that the factory was the problem because it created a new service with every call ... I removed the factory and now it's working :)